# SQL - how to query two tables and return the results as one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, coldfusion

Long story short, I have this website where "Parent" level comments are stored in a separate table than their replies, known as "Child" comments.

To produce a list of all Recent Comments, I've been doing something like this:

```
SELECT
TOP 10 
 PC.ParentCommentText,
 PC.ParentCommentID,
 PC.ParentCommentTimeStamp
FROM
  ParentComments AS PC
```

We'll call that Query1.

Query2 is the same:

```
SELECT
TOP 10 
 CC.ChildCommentText,
 CC.ChildCommentID,
 CC.ChildCommentTimeStamp
FROM
  ChildComments AS CC
```

Then I use a Union and query the queries so I can loop through all the results at once and display a mixed list of most recent.

```
SELECT * FROM Query1
UNION 
SELECT * FROM Query2
ORDER BY ParentCommentTimeStamp DESC
```

My problem starts with the first two queries - I can only return a certain number from either table to start. So if some thread runs away and becomes a big discussion, all the slots for "Child" comments are filled, and you might still see "Parent" comments that are hours or days old, despite them not being anywhere near Recent.

It's been awhile since I've done anything requiring deep knowledge of SQL. I know there's a way to select Parent and Child comments as one, and just grab __ number of the results, despite which table they originated from.

Help?

Comment: Note - this is tagged Coldfusion as well. That is my serverside language for this endeavor and I am open to solutions that are not purely SQL. Although that is preferred.

Comment: can you show some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: I just want to combine results from both tables without limiting myself to, for example, 10 of each. I want ALL the results from either table, in one query object, just sorted by their timestamp. So if I wanted the 20 most recent comments, I might get 18 Child comments and 2 Parents. Right now I get the 10 most recent of each no matter what.

Comment: How do you relate a Child Comment to its Parent Comment?

Comment: the Child Comment table has a column for the Parent ID that's filled out when the comment is made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `union all` to combine the query results and `order by` later to get the top n rows.

```
SELECT TOP 10 WITH TIES *
FROM (SELECT ParentCommentText,ParentCommentID,ParentCommentTimeStamp as comment_timestamp
      FROM ParentComments 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT ChildCommentText,ChildCommentID,ChildCommentTimeStamp
      FROM ChildComments
     ) T
ORDER BY comment_timestamp DESC
```